# Adding a Channel to a MS Teams site with PnP PowerShell results in a Skype error

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Using Add-PnPTeamsChannel to add an un-hidden (-IsFavoriteByDefault) channel to a Microsoft Team authenticated as a GA with Connect-PnPOnline results in the below error, but correctly adds the channel.

```
Add-PnPTeamsChannel: Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest.
```

Anyone know what causes this?

Have repeated the test with multiple channel configurations and all result in the same error, but still correctly create the channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it works:

```
Add-PnPTeamsChannel -Team myTeamGUID -DisplayName "MyChannelName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```